# Exclude groups with NAs in tidy dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I have a tidy `tibble` with a value column identified by 4 ID columns.

```
 > MWA
# A tibble: 16 x 5
# Groups:   Dir [2]
      VP   Con   Dir   Seg time_seg
   <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
 1    10     2     1     1     1810
 2    10     2     1     2      260
 3    10     2     1     3      540
 4    10     2     1     4     1470
 5    10     2     1     5      460
 6    10     2     1     6      690
 7    10     2     1     7      760
 8    10     2     1     8       NA
 9    10     2     2     1      320
10    10     2     2     2     1110
11    10     2     2     3      450
12    10     2     2     4      600
13    10     2     2     5     1680
14    10     2     2     6      730
15    10     2     2     7      850
16    10     2     2     8      840
```

The `dput` to reproduce is

```
> dput(MWA)
structure(list(VP = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Con = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Dir = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
    Seg = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L), time_seg = c(1810L, 260L, 540L, 1470L, 460L, 
    690L, 760L, NA, 320L, 1110L, 450L, 600L, 1680L, 730L, 850L, 
    840L)), row.names = c(NA, -16L), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), vars = "Dir", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
    0:7, 8:15), group_sizes = c(8L, 8L), biggest_group_size = 8L, labels = structure(list(
    Dir = 1:2), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame", vars = "Dir", drop = TRUE))
```

They stem from a larger data set, where they have been grouped by `VP`, `Con` and finally `Dir`.

As you can see, in tibble row 10 there is a `NA`.

I now want to exclude the whole `Dir` group (so rows 1 trough 8), based on this condition that this one value is missing using `dplyr`.

Using the `filter` with `is.na` or `complete.cases` only removes the row with the `NA`, not the complete group (which is one "case" in this dataset).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `all()` will evaluate the entire group, so you can skip the `mutate` step.

```
MWA %>% 
  group_by(Dir) %>% 
  filter(all(!is.na(time_seg)))

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   Dir [1]
     VP   Con   Dir   Seg time_seg
  <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
1    10     2     2     1      320
2    10     2     2     2     1110
3    10     2     2     3      450
4    10     2     2     4      600
5    10     2     2     5     1680
6    10     2     2     6      730
7    10     2     2     7      850
8    10     2     2     8      840
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first check whether there is any missing value in the specific column and then exclude the whole group.

```
library(dplyr)

MWA %>% 
  group_by(VP, Con, Dir) %>% 
  mutate(any_na = any(is.na(time_seg))) %>% 
  filter(!any_na)

# A tibble: 8 x 6
# Groups:   VP, Con, Dir [1]
#     VP   Con   Dir   Seg time_seg any_na
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int> <lgl> 
# 1    10     2     2     1      320 FALSE 
# 2    10     2     2     2     1110 FALSE 
# 3    10     2     2     3      450 FALSE 
# 4    10     2     2     4      600 FALSE 
# 5    10     2     2     5     1680 FALSE 
# 6    10     2     2     6      730 FALSE 
# 7    10     2     2     7      850 FALSE 
# 8    10     2     2     8      840 FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

There is `anyNA` in `base R`

```
library(dplyr)
MWA %>%
    group_by(Dir) %>%
    filter(!anyNA(time_seg))
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   Dir [1]
#     VP   Con   Dir   Seg time_seg
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>    <int>
#1    10     2     2     1      320
#2    10     2     2     2     1110
#3    10     2     2     3      450
#4    10     2     2     4      600
#5    10     2     2     5     1680
#6    10     2     2     6      730
#7    10     2     2     7      850
#8    10     2     2     8      840
```